# How to view all Gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle

I run a `gradle build` in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:8.2.0-jdk17-focal as build

ARG version=dev

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

RUN echo "Running gradle build" && gradle --info --no-daemon build -Pversion=${version}
```

After `gradle build`, I want to view all downloaded jar files. As I added `--info`, so I can see build logs shows:

```
Downloading https://mymirror.com/maven/org/xmlunit/xmlunit-parent/2.9.0/xmlunit-parent-2.9.0.pom to /home/gradle/.gradle/.tmp/gradle_download15345264528744425254bin
```

It downloaded `xmlunit-parent/2.9.0`, however `gradle.lockfile` contains only `org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.9.0` rather than `xmlunit-parent`. So I guess `xmlunit-parent` is an indirect dependency.

I tried to find it from `/home/gradle/.gradle/.tmp`, but looks like once `gradle build` finishes, `/home/gradle/.gradle/.tmp` is deleted.

I also tried `gradle dependencies`, it doesn't show `xmlunit-parent`. How can I get a full list of downloaded dependent jars?

Comment: What do you want to do with those jars? Have you tried a [Build Scan®️](https://scans.gradle.com/#gradle) via `--scan`? If you must run it in a container, you might need to run the container in interactive mode with `-it` as it will prompt for confirmation.